# lassCastException: io.flutter.app.FlutterPluginRegistry cannot be cast to io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngine

Tags: flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging, flutter-dependencies

When we uninstall the app and load first time notificaiotn is working but after that it showing this errors

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create service
>   io.flutter.plugins.firebasemessaging.FlutterFirebaseMessagingService:
>   java.lang.ClassCastException: io.flutter.app.FlutterPluginRegistry
>   cannot be cast to io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngine
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:3976)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap5(Unknown Source:0)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2109)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:109)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:166)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7555)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:469)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:963)
>        Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: io.flutter.app.FlutterPluginRegistry cannot be cast to
>   io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngine
>           at com.midhilaj.aquarium_shop.Application.registerWith(Application.java:25)
>           at io.flutter.plugins.firebasemessaging.FlutterFirebaseMessagingService.startBackgroundIsolate(FlutterFirebaseMessagingService.java:164)
>           at io.flutter.plugins.firebasemessaging.FlutterFirebaseMessagingService.onCreate(FlutterFirebaseMessagingService.java:77)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:3956)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap5(Unknown Source:0) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2109) 
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:109) 
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:166) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7555) 
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>           at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:469) 
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:963)

> D/FlutterActivity( 3682): Using the launch theme as normal theme.
>   D/FlutterActivityAndFragmentDelegate( 3682): Setting up FlutterEngine.
>   D/FlutterActivityAndFragmentDelegate( 3682): No preferred
>   FlutterEngine was provided. Creating a new FlutterEngine for this
>   FlutterFragment. D/FlutterActivityAndFragmentDelegate( 3682):
>   Attaching FlutterEngine to the Activity that owns this Fragment.
>   D/FlutterView( 3682): Detaching from a FlutterEngine: null
>   D/FlutterView( 3682): Not attached to an engine. Doing nothing.
>   D/FlutterView( 3682): Attaching to a FlutterEngine:
>   io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngine@54b88a0
>   D/FlutterActivityAndFragmentDelegate( 3682): Executing Dart
>   entrypoint: main, and sending initial route: / Syncing files to device
>   DUB LX1... I/flutter ( 3682):
>   -----=--token:db37iEIOPw2r5Y9LpYpXz-H
>   V/FA      ( 3682): Inactivity, disconnecting from the service
>   I/flutter ( 3682): e222banner1 => {actionPage: null, buttonLabel:
>   null, buttonLabelAr: null, img:
>   https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/,
>   subTitle: null, subTitleAr: null, title: Gold FIsh, titleAr: null}
>   I/flutter ( 3682): getMyCart fn I/flutter ( 3682): e222banner2 =>
>   {actionPage: null, buttonLabel: null, buttonLabelAr: null, img:
>   https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/ ,
>   subTitle: null, subTitleAr: null, title: Gold FIsh, titleAr: null}
>   I/flutter ( 3682): getMyCart user 6AiQ2pG8nsaskpcUbbyJM7eCPuR2
>   D/ConnectivityManager( 3682): requestNetwork and the calling app is:
>   com.midhilaj.aquarium_shop W/DynamiteModule( 3682): Local module
>   descriptor class for providerinstaller not found. I/DynamiteModule(
>   3682): Considering local module providerinstaller:0 and remote module
>   providerinstaller:0 W/ProviderInstaller( 3682): Failed to load
>   providerinstaller module: No acceptable module found. Local version is
>   0 and remote version is 0. D/HwFLClassLoader( 3682): USE_FEATURE_LIST
>   had not init!  W/zygote64( 3682): ClassLoaderContext classpath size
>   mismatch for position 0. expected=0, found=1 (PCL[] |
>   PCL[/system/framework/com.android.media.remotedisplay.jar*818632460])
>   V/NativeCrypto( 3682): Registering
>   com/google/android/gms/org/conscrypt/NativeCrypto's 286 native
>   methods... D/NetworkSecurityConfig( 3682): No Network Security Config
>   specified, using platform default I/ProviderInstaller( 3682):
>   Installed default security provider GmsCore_OpenSSL
>   D/ConnectivityManager( 3682): requestNetwork and the calling app is:
>   com.midhilaj.aquarium_shop I/zygote64( 3682): Do partial code cache
>   collection, code=60KB, data=46KB I/zygote64( 3682): After code cache
>   collection, code=60KB, data=46KB I/zygote64( 3682): Increasing code
>   cache capacity to 256KB I/zygote64( 3682): Starting profile saver
>   IsSaveProfileNow end. I/flutter ( 3682): snapshot is  null
>   D/AndroidRuntime( 3682): Shutting down VM E/AndroidRuntime( 3682):
>   FATAL EXCEPTION: main E/AndroidRuntime( 3682): Process:
>   com.midhilaj.aquarium_shop, PID: 3682 E/AndroidRuntime( 3682):
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create service
>   io.flutter.plugins.firebasemessaging.FlutterFirebaseMessagingService:
>   java.lang.ClassCastException: io.flutter.app.FlutterPluginRegistry
>   cannot be cast to io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngine
>   E/AndroidRuntime( 3682):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:3976)
>   E/AndroidRuntime( 3682):  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap5(Unknown
>   Source:0) E/AndroidRuntime( 3682):    at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2109)
>   E/AndroidRuntime( 3682):  at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:109) E/AndroidRuntime(
>   3682):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:166) E/AndroidRuntime(
>   3682):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7555)
>   E/AndroidRuntime( 3682):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native
>   Method) E/AndroidRuntime( 3682):  at
>   com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:469)
>   E/AndroidRuntime( 3682):  at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:963)
>   E/AndroidRuntime( 3682): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   io.flutter.app.FlutterPluginRegistry cannot be cast to
>   io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngine E/AndroidRuntime( 3682):    at
>   com.midhilaj.aquarium_shop.Application.registerWith(Application.java:25)
>   E/AndroidRuntime( 3682):  at
>   io.flutter.plugins.firebasemessaging.FlutterFirebaseMessagingService.startBackgroundIsolate(FlutterFirebaseMessagingService.java:164)
>   E/AndroidRuntime( 3682):  at
>   io.flutter.plugins.firebasemessaging.FlutterFirebaseMessagingService.onCreate(FlutterFirebaseMessagingService.java:77)
>   E/AndroidRuntime( 3682):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:3956)
>   E/AndroidRuntime( 3682):  ... 8 more I/Process ( 3682): Sending
>   signal. PID: 3682 SIG: 9 Lost connection to device.

```
import io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication;
import io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngine;
import io.flutter.plugin.common.PluginRegistry;
import io.flutter.plugin.common.PluginRegistry.PluginRegistrantCallback;

import io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication;
import io.flutter.plugin.common.PluginRegistry;
import io.flutter.plugin.common.PluginRegistry.PluginRegistrantCallback;
import io.flutter.plugins.GeneratedPluginRegistrant;
import io.flutter.plugins.firebasemessaging.FlutterFirebaseMessagingService;

public class Application extends FlutterApplication implements PluginRegistrantCallback {
    FlutterEngine fe;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        FlutterFirebaseMessagingService.setPluginRegistrant(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void registerWith(PluginRegistry registry) {
        GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith((FlutterEngine) registry);
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you find a solution to this yet?

Comment: yes, i fixed that issue

Comment: Please share how you did that

Comment: @Midhilaj can you please share the solution with us

Answer (score 1):

**Use FlutterEngine this way**

*It's solved my problem*

```
GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(FlutterEngine(applicationContext));
```

Answer (score 0):

Been through countless posts and answers until i saw this : [Migration guide](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Upgrading-pre-1.12-Android-projects)
It's a migration guide for the new flutter versions. My takeway is

> The new FlutterActivity/ Flutter Application no longer requires manually registering your
> plugins. It will now perform the registration automatically when the
> underlaying FlutterEngine is created.

```
    override fun registerWith(registry: PluginRegistry) {
            // comment the below methods out or remove the method 
           // GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(FlutterEngine(applicationContext));
          // GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith((registry as FlutterEngine?)!!)
        }
```